# What is the meaning behind the name Catfish and The Bottlemen?

Tags: meaning, indie

I find this name fairly weird, where does it derive from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name comes from 'Van' Mccann's, the lead singer, first musical memory. as a child, he and his parents spent a large amount of time travelling Australia. He came across a street busker in Sydney who played music using beer bottles. The busker went by the name of Catfish The Bottleman so he used this as the name of his band.